Tipos de Datos(Boolean/bit) en SQL
Tengo una tabla en un contenedor de Azure, y los datos los leemos mediante una tabla en Synapse, en SQL, la tabla contiene una columna, llamada "CentroActivado", veo que en el contenedor tiene el tipo de dato de "boolean",

Pero al leer la tabla en Synapse veo que en sql tiene el tipo de dato "bit",

Sobre esta tabla, yo debo crear una vista que tenga esta condicion en el WHERE:  AND CentroActivado= 'TRUE', me doy cuenta que si la hago asi, si me da los datos que deben de ser(ya que en la tabla origen no hay ningun dato con TRUE).
Pero quisiera saber si hay un problema si le dejo  en el where le dejo el "TRUE" o como "1", Que diferencia hay?, el dato lo presenta bien si lo hago de ambas formas? Que seria lo recomendable?
